# Install gruobipy package - error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gurobi

I can not install the Python package Gurobipy. I get the following output when I try it:

> running install
>
> running build running build_py running install_lib running
>
> install_egg_info Removing
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy-7.5.1.egg-info Writing
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy-7.5.1.egg-info
>
> removing 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' (and everything under it)
>
> 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it
>
> 'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it removing 'build'

I run Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7, and Gurobi 7.5.1. gurobi.sh is working fine...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is python 2 supported? `build/scripts-2.7' does not exist`... Sounds like not

Answer (score 0):

You can test gurobipy via the command `from gurobipy import *`. If that gives no error, then the installation worked, and you can ignore the messages from running setup.py.

Comment: Using Gurobi 7.0.2 I don't get the error while installing gurobipy but still it does not work.... while execution: `ImportError: libgurobi75.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Most likely, you need to setup the environment variables: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html